# Turn a load on with a pulse of power, keep on until (NO) button is pressed

Tags: switches, analog

I have a device that sends a pulse +12V when access is confirmed. I would like to keep a relay live until a button is pressed to close the circuit.

This is used to start up a cars (acc) and allow it to start. Then when I exit I will press the button and it's all off. I am lost as to what to search for and the ways to make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple latching relay circuit requires a NC button (or a NC/NO button or switch, one that has both states depending on how its pressed/switched). As Vlad has shown.

There is also a latching relay that depends on Acc/On switched power, where it turns off once the car is turned off, and only turns on when you press the button when the car is on.

But if you add a second relay, you get the pulsed on, and NO button setup you want.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZWhdb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Trigger the circuit, Relay 2's Normally Closed contact allows Relay 1 to activate, latching it from the 12V power source through Relay 1's Normally Open contact. Circuit will stay on until 12V power is lost, or until Relay 2 is activated by grounding the coil through the Normally Open Button. D1 and D2 are protection diodes for the Relay, while D3 is there to prevent backfeed to the trigger.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a circuit that will work for you:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4L9kl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When a pulse drives D1 the relay turns on. The first relay switch connects the coil to a +12V rail through SW1, that is a normally closed push button. The second switch gets closed too and can be used for any purpose.

When you want to turn off your rig you simply push SW1 thus disconnecting the relay coil and opening both switches: when SW1 will be released the relay won't turn back on.

D1 is there to prevent current from the +12V to flow back to the pulse generation circuit, that might or might not like it. If the pulse generator circuit is just a momentary switch connected to the same +12V you can safely remove D1.

Please note that I am assuming that the pulse will last long enough to turn on the relay and toggle the switches. some 100ish of ms should be enough. If your pulse is very short, i.e. 1ms or less, you will probably need a more sophisticated circuit.

I know that this topology has a name, in italian it sounds like "relay with auto hold". If someone can point it out I'd gladly add it. Thanks to Passerby I've learnt that this is called **(Self) Latching Relay Circuit**, that is **not** a latching relay that normally includes two coils.

**edit**

I see that in the title you say your switch is a normally open one. The easiest and safest way to use a NO that comes to my mind is to use a NC SPST or a SPDT relay to invert the behaviour of the disengage button as in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/126873/16993) answer from Passerby. Or substitute it with a NC button already.

Comment: Love it that is what I was looking for I was thinking about using npn transistors but a relay not only works but it saves me stepping up the available amps to run the car.

Comment: please note that if the rest of the equipment runs from the +12V you just need a SPST NO relay, your output is the same terminal that powers the relay coil, just hook it up *before* the disengage button so that it can be rated for less current

Comment: Self Latching Relay Circuit. Or Simply Latching Relay Circuit. Not to be confused with a Latching Relay (Typically has two coils).

Comment: This is the exact circuit used for start/stop pushbuttons in industrial motor control circuits.

Answer (score 0):

You need a bistable relay such as [this one](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1717900.pdf). It has two coils, one coil permanently switches to one position and the second coil to the other.

Comment: Never heard of such a relay I love that idea as well!